# How to count the number of highlighted cells?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can you please guys me help writing a piece of code which takes some data range as a parameter from a Column e.g; D column and D1 to 100. Now what I want is that the function counts the number of cells that are highlighted with a color and return the number of that cells.

I can barely write any code as I've very little knowledge, however, I've tried but no such luck. So, I thought to ask you guys

[image: You can see the image here].

Comment: Stack isn't a code writing service, unfortunately, Rose. It would be best to post your attempt and what errors you got and then people can guide you from there. For example, you've stated that it should return the number of highlighted cells but you haven't said where is should return them.

Comment: If  you have code, then you should post it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) method from the  [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) to get an array with all the cell's color values and then check if it is the color you want. Using this code you can achieve what you want:

```
/*
   colA1: The column letter for example A,B,C, AA..
   rangeStart: Where to start the range
   rangeEnd: Where to end the range
*/
function numberHighlightedCells(colA1, rangeStart, rangeEnd){
  // Set the color for comparation 
  var color = '#ff0000';
  // Build the range with the parameters values
  var customRange = colA1 + rangeStart.toString() + ":" + colA1 + rangeEnd.toString();
  // Get the range
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(customRange);
  // Get an array containing all colors 
  range.getBackgrounds().forEach(function(e, index){
    // Verify if the desired color is in the cell 
    if( e[0] === color) Logger.log("Cell number " + (index + 1).toString())
  });
}
```